# Can anyone give me advice on how to replace the number of letters with asterisks?

Tags: ruby

Here is my code and output below, i would like to have it so that instead of saying how many occurences, it would output the number of times the letter appears in asterisk form.

For exmaple if "a" appeared four times within a sentence the output would produce:
`"a": ****`

```
the_file='C:\Users\Jack\Documents\Ruby\Lab1\lyric.txt'
h = Hash.new
f = File.open(the_file, "r")
f.each_line { |line|
  words = line.split(//)
  words.each { |w|
    if h.has_key?(w)
      h[w] = h[w] + 1
    else
      h[w] = 1
    end
  }
}

# sort the hash by value, and then print it in this sorted order

h.sort{|a,b| a[1]<=>b[1]}.each { |elem|
  puts "\"#{elem[0]}\" : #{elem[1]} occurrences"
}
```

Screenshot of my current program and output
[image]

Comment: Could you include a minimal working example of your code in your question so we don't have to type it out if we want to debug it?

Comment: sorry ill do it now

Comment: `words` are not words.

Comment: Standard Ruby style is to [use `do` and `end` rather than curly braces](https://github.com/rubocop-hq/ruby-style-guide#single-line-blocks) when the block is expressed on multiple lines.

Comment: so instead of putting a bracket just say end at the last point?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `#{elem[1]} occurences` you just need to write `#{'*' * elem[1]}`

See [method description](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/String.html#method-i-2A) for more details.

Answer (score 2):

I would like to show another possible alternative way to achieve the word count.
Letting apart the file reading, let's consider the following string:

```
line = 'Here is my code and output below, i would like to have it so that instead of saying how many occurrences, it would output the number of times the letter appears in asterisk form.'

h = Hash.new(0)
line.downcase.each_char{ |ch| h[ch] += 1 if ('a'..'z').include? ch }
h.to_a.sort_by(&:last).reverse.each { |ch, count| puts "#{ch}: " + "*" * count}
```

- Initialise the hash with `default = 0` allow you to start the count without checking if key exists: [`Hash#default`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Hash.html#method-i-default).
- Iterate over the line by [`String#each_char`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/String.html#method-i-each_char)
- I counted only case insensitive letters, up to you
- For sorting change the Hash into an Array with [`Hash#to_a`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Hash.html#method-i-to_a)
- For printing the histogram, as shown in other posts

Answer (score 0):

```
puts "\"#{elem[0]}\": " + '*' * elem[1]
```

`+` for concatenate, `string` `*` `number` is to repeat certain string `number` times.

Answer (score 0):

With strings in Ruby, you can use math operators against them. So, you know how many times the letter appears (in `elem[1]`). In that case you can just multiply the asterisks symbol by that amount:

`"\"#{elem[0]}: #{'*' * elem[1]}\""`

Comment: I have tried replacing the file so it would have input instead like below, sorry im very new to this.
`print "Please enter any length of text:"`
`user_input = String(gets.chomp)`
`h = Hash.new`
`f = user_input`
`f.each_line { |line|`